# how to dynamically name objects in a game animation?

Tags: javascript, object, animation

I'm trying to develop a game in JS using a framework.

So far I'm to the point where I have multiple animations for a character and I need to be able to run my animation function (which is actually adding a component to a character object, the component creates and manages all animations for that character) for different animations.

Suppose the player presses the 'a' key which executes X action, compared to if they press 'b' which executes Y action.

At the current moment, I detect which key was pressed, and then use a `switch / case` function to set my current animation and then push it through to my animation component.

It works perfectly, but the problem is for every new animation, I'm doing something like:

```
switch (keydown){
   case 65: // 'a' key was pressed
       character.animation = myAnimationComponent.animation.a;
       break;
   case 66: // 'b' key was pressed
       character.animation = myAnimationComponent.animation.b;
       break;
}
// something happens to 'animation' that renders it on the screen
```

Assuming I actually store the animation value (aka 'a' or 'b') into the keydown object, I can get it out:
   `keydown.animation;`
prints `a`

so instead of having a switch or if/else case for every animation, how can i pass the animation value into the object so that i don't need a case for every single animation, e.i.:

```
animation =  myAnimationComponent.animation.?keydown.animation?;
```

(keydown.animation should output 'a' or 'b')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
var animType = String.fromCharCode(keydown);
if(animType){
     animation = myAnimationComponent.animation[animType];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the `keydown` value as the key in your object

```
animation =  myAnimationComponent.animation[keydown];
```

Then when you retrieve it later you could pass it to a function that translates the numerical value to the alphabetic character

```
String.fromCharCode(97 + animation);
```